# Permission sets with namespace

Tags: permission-sets, namespace

It seems some permission sets permissions can not be edited at all (the Edit button is missing)

It seems this is for permission sets with a namespace and these are installed as part of a managed package. However some permission sets have namespace "force" but this managed package is not listed in the "Installed package" UI

Does anyone know are there permission sets with a namespace that can be edited ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A benefit of un-editable permission sets with a namespace for a managed package vendor is that the permission sets can be updated by the vendor as new capabilities are added (e.g. new Apex classes or new objects and fields). The package upgrade process updates the permission sets.

If the permission sets were locally editable, then that upgrade process would overwrite the local changes which is unlikely to be what anyone wants. I think if the package is an unmanaged package the namespaced permission set can be edited. But the next upgrade of the package will overwrite those changes.

I'm not familiar with the "force" namespace.

If you want to modify permissions, best you add your own permission set. If you want to remove permissions, use a permission set group and its [muting mechanism](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_muting.htm&type=5).